# Angular & Firebase list not updating

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i'm new with both Angular & Firebase. I've been trying to create a factory to update my list of stations but the list just won't seem to update.
When i run the factory code `firebase.database...` in my controller it works fine though.

`controller`

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function ($scope,Stations) {

        $scope.stations = [];
        $scope.stations = Stations.getStations();
    })
```

`services`

```
.factory('Stations', function() {
    return {
        getStations : function(){
            firebase.database().ref('stations').once('value',function(snapshot){
                console.log(snapshot.val());
                return snapshot.val();
            })
        }
    }
})
```

What am i doing wrong? Isn't the `ng-repeat="(key,station) in stations"` list supposed to change after the factory returns the new data ?

Also I've been noticing something in a few tutorials. What is the difference between the below 2 inits.

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function ($scope,Stations) {

        $scope.stations = [];
        $scope.stations = Stations.getStations();
    })

.controller('DashCtrl', [$scope,Stations,function ($scope,Stations) {

        $scope.stations = [];
        $scope.stations = Stations.getStations();
    }])
```

Comment: Just to make it clear for the edit, the problem isn't with the databaes not returning anything rather than updating the ng-repeat list on return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you didn't wrap the firebase result with an Angular promise, the angular environment cannot notice there are new results arrived, you have two solutions:

1. using [Angular Fire](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire) which provide angular bindings for firebase
2. wrap the return result with an `$q` promise:

   ```
   //controller 
   .controller('DashCtrl', function ($scope,Stations) {
       $scope.stations = [];
       Stations.getStations().then(function(results){
           $scope.stations = results;
       });
    })

   //service
   .factory('Stations', function($q) {
       return {
           getStations : function(){
               var defer = $q.defer();
               firebase.database().ref('stations').once('value').then(function(snapshot){
                   defer.resolve(snapshot.val());
               }).catch(function(error){
                   defer.reject(error);
               })
               return defer.promise;
           }
       }
   })
   ```

Comment: ok I got it, but i'll be using this one if i want to use `once`. What about `on` ? how could i let know the controller to update the list from the Stations factory ?

Answer (score 1):

controller #1

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function ($scope,Stations) {

    $scope.stations = [];
    $scope.stations = Stations.getStations();
})
```

controller #2

```
.controller('DashCtrl', [$scope,Stations,function ($scope,Stations) {

    $scope.stations = [];
    $scope.stations = Stations.getStations();
}])
```

controller #2 is better for **minification** done by browsers which will result something like:

controller2.min.js

```
.controller('DashCtrl', [a,b, function(a,b) {

a.stations = [];
a.stations = b.getStations();
}])
```